# WPF XAML How can I conditionally perform this animation?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, conditional-statements

How do I conditionally get this animation to run, depending on a `bool CanAnimate`? It works right now, but I don't always want it to be animated, I want to check the boolean.

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="1" Name="ReviewNote">
   <Border.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.Loaded">
         <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
               <DoubleAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="ReviewNote"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Opacity)"
                    From="1.0" To="0.0" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
   </Border.Triggers>
   <TextBlock Text="{x:Static Constants:StringConstants.ReviewNote}" 
              Background="{StaticResource ReviewNoteColor}" Width="100" 
              TextAlignment="Center" />
</Border>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply style on your border and inside style you can check value of bool property. Based on that property you can specify `DataTrigger.EnterActions` with storyboard after removing TargetName from storyBoard.

This will work -

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" Margin="1" Name="ReviewNote">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
           <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanAnimate}" Value="True">
                   <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                       <BeginStoryboard>
                           <Storyboard>
                              <DoubleAnimation 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Opacity)"
                                    From="1.0" To="0.0" AutoReverse="True" 
                                    RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                            </Storyboard>
                       </BeginStoryboard>
                   </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </Border.Style>
   <TextBlock/>
</Border>
```

Comment: hmm how do i stop the animation when my boolean becomes false?  it seems to just animate forever without ever checking the boolean again.  The boolean is set inside a SelectedItem setter...

Comment: thanks, i figured out how to stop it using ExitActions and StopStoryBoard

Comment: Yeah you can use `ExitActions`. :)